# When deriving Leibniz Integral rule, why not take $f$ as another variable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

In a review of multivariable calculus, I tried to rederive Leibniz integral rule on my own. I started by
$$I(a(x),b(x),f(x))=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)\mathrm{d}t$$
Then, using the chain rule: 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}I}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\partial I}{\partial a}\frac{\mathrm{d}a}{\mathrm{d}x}+\frac{\partial I}{\partial b}\frac{\mathrm{d}b}{\mathrm{d}x}+\frac{\partial I}{\partial f}\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}$$
The first two terms are easy, but the last one I could not solve. When I checked to see the derivation, it starts by saying
$$ I(a(x),b(x),x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)\mathrm{d}t$$
My question is: why can we not take $f$ to be a variable like the others? I have thought about it but the only think I could come up with is that it is somehow fixed or that the integral determines it, but these justifications are flimsy at best. I would like to know the real explanation.

Comment: You can treat $f$ as a variable, but it's a variable which depends on $x$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr How would I compute $\partial I/\partial f$?

Comment: You have $f(x)$ and $f(x,t)$? Pick one. What do you mean by take $f$ to be a variable?

Comment: @copper.hat Why can I not take $f$ to be like $a$ or $b$?

Comment: You can, but you need to specify what space $f$ lives in.

Comment: @copper.hat If I picked $f(x)$?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: @copper.hat What do you mean by "what space $f$ lives in"?

Comment: What do you mean by take $f$ to be a variable? $f$ is a function, soit must live in some function space.

Comment: @copper.hat Like $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$?